# Is elastic net equivalent in scikit-learn and glmnet?

Tags: scikit-learn, glmnet

In particular, glmnet [docs](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) imply it creates a "Generalised Linear Model" of the gaussian family for regression, while scikit-learn imply no such thing (ie, seems like it's a pure linear regression, not generalised). But I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation you link to, there is an optimization problem which shows exactly what is optimized in GLMnet:

```
1/(2N) * sum_i(y_i - beta_0 - x_i^T beta) + lambda * [(1 - alpha)/2 ||beta||_2^2 + alpha * ||beta||_1]
```

Now take a look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#elastic-net), where you will find the same formula written as the optimization of a euclidean norm. Note that the docs have omitted the intercept `w_0`, equivalent to `beta_0`, but the code does estimate it.
Please also note that `lambda` becomes `alpha` and `alpha` becomes `rho`...

The "Gaussian family" aspect probably refers to the fact that an L2-loss is used, which corresponds to assuming that the noise is additive Gaussian.